# How to implement Android's contacts list scroll index effect?

Tags: android, scrollbar, alphabetical-sort, fastscroll

I would like to achieve Android contact's list scroll effect.

I found some similar custom implementations but not the same.

As always, Google creates awesome experiences on its default apps but doesn't add it to the native framework library.

This scrollbar is available on the contacts list since KitKat =/

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found in Android Developers page this [list of contacts example](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) and they're implementing this exact effect.

Comment: this? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html

Comment: SectionIndexer is the widget that I will use to order and split my list alphabetically, but what I'm asking is:
How can I make a scrollbar with the effect like in image?

Comment: If I may add an off topic tip. Don't use iOS interfaces on android. Android users really don't like that

Comment: I agree, the first image is from an old app.
And because this, I want to make an scrollbar like the one in the second image (used in my Nexus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Years later I found this cool [L4Digital/FastScroll library](https://github.com/L4Digital/FastScroll) that easily achieves the exact same effect I was looking for.

We're working with this library in production with a large user base app w/o any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638551/android-fastscrolling-sectionindexer-getsections-is-called-only-once), but [this is the google search you're looking for.](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20fast%20scroll%20bar&oq=android%20quick%20scroll%20bar&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j0.6544j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20listview%20fastscroll%20sectionindexer&safe=off) Theres always [androids documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I updated my question, cause was not clear.
I have an example using SectionIndexer to order and split alphabetically, but is really old and ugly